# Как можно удалить все, кроме цены в строке с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, любой-язык

Имеется паттерн

```
\\D+[^.]\\D+
```

По нему я удаляю все, кроме цены в строке. Но если в цене точность в десятых, то цена округляется

```
String s = "100.5 рублей.";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\D+[^.]\\D+", ""));
```

Результаты:

```
100.5 рублей > 100
100.50 рублей > 100.50
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: @Visman, да, я знаю, у меня сначала было `\\d+[.]\\d+`, он удалял саму цену, я не знал куда писать ^ для всего паттерна и перевернул логику в каждой его части

Comment: а нельзя использовать match вмето replaceAll и выделять саму цену?

Comment: или replaceAll() с двумя параметрами `replaceAll("^.*?\\(\\d+[.]\\d+\\).*$","\1")`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо большое. Выложите в ответ, пожалуйста, и расзложите его по полочкам, если не трудно

Comment: @Fat-Zer, кстати он не работает

Comment: Скобки, скорей всего, не надо эскейпить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "100.5 рублей.";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^.*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*$", "\\1"));
```

Регулярное выражение:

- `^` — начало строки, в данном случае не обязательно.
- `.*?` — ленивый выбор всех символов (подразумевая, что диалект его поддерживает)
- `(\d+\.\d+)` — выбор числа
- `.*` — выбор всех символов, что остались в строке
- `$` — конец строки (также не обязателен)

Выражение для замены:

- `"\1"` — замена строки, сопоставленной всему выражению на строку сопоставленную первому выражению в скобках

---

Более продуктивно использовать метод `match('\d+\.\d+')` (matchSubstr,find или как-то ещё); конкретика зависит от языка/библиотеки.

---

*Набор символов, которые необходимо ескейпить (скобки, плюс) зависят от диалекта.